# Can you modify ACLOCAL_PATH from configure.ac?

Tags: configure, autoconf

A user of [xnec2c](https://www.xnec2c.org/) was trying to build on OSX and had [autoconf issues](https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/issues/16) because [PKG_CHECK_MODULES could not be found since MacPorts puts it in a funny spot](https://tgebarowski.github.io/2008/08/31/problem-with-pkg_check_modules-under-mac-os-x/).

The user made autoconf work like so:

```bash
ACLOCAL_PATH=/opt/local/share/aclocal ./autogen.sh 
ACLOCAL_PATH=/opt/local/share/aclocal ./configure
```

I would like to make it build on OSX without special user path hacks for `ACLOCAL_PATH`.  Can that be done?

I started writing a possible fix below and realized it could an [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info) so posed the question just above.  However, if this starts any gears turning, then I would be open to a bit of special-casing for OSX:

For example, would it be possible (if not advisable) to detect:

1. Is PKG_CHECK_MODULES missing?
2. If so:

- is it OSX?
- Is [ -d /opt/local/share/aclocal ] true?
- Does the macro exist there?

Comment: MacPorts suffers considerably from a lack of attention where some packages just don't build properly. Does Homebrew have the same issue with this package? I'd suggest this is a MacPorts bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @tadman, not sure, I suggested brew, too, but they are sticking with macports.  If I had an OSX system then it would be nice to test, but I dont.  If you're interested in trying, then building xnec2c is pretty strait forward: https://www.xnec2c.org/

Comment: While I used MacPorts for years, I've been on Homebrew for a long time now and it's been fantastic. If there's some stubborn group that refuses to move, you should probably either A) patch that package, or B) make your own custom variant. MacPorts is notoriously flaky in many departments, but if you're prepared to fix the existing installer's deficiencies you may help remedy a tiny bit of that.

Comment: @tadman, good to know.  I'm curious if it works fine in brew Homebrew if you have a minute to fire off a build. If not then I understand, no pressure!  (Someday it would be nice to have a .dmg for OSX users of xnec2c)

Comment: Nothing [found in the default ports](https://formulae.brew.sh) which is actually surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `aclocal` has a few ways of appending to its search path (see https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Macro-Search-Path.html), you cannot modify that macro search path using code in `configure.ac`:

When the shell code in `configure` is run, it is too late, as the available macros have already been expanded. When `autoconf` (is it `autoconf` or something else? anyway, `m4` called from `autoreconf`) generates `configure` from `configure.ac` by having `m4` expand the macros it is also too late: `aclocal` has already collected the m4 macros it could find.

So what you would need is a step before the `autoreconf` run - which is beyond what I would consider a buildsystem needs to do.

What you *can* do: Put static strings into the top level `Makefile.am` file like e.g.

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I auto-m4 -I project-m4 -I /opt/local/share/aclocal
```

(this example uses `auto-m4/` with `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([auto-m4])` for the `*.m4` files automatically put there by `autoreconf`/`autopoint`/`libtoolize` and `project-m4/` for the project specific `*.m4` files).

Of course, you should already have

```
m4_pattern_forbid([PKG_CHECK_MODULES])dnl
```

before invoking `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` for the first time so that the problem of the missing `*.m4` file will be detected at the earliest possible time, i.e. when `autoconf` is about to generate a `configure` file with `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` unexpanded.

You **could** use some `m4` code to print a lengthy error message if `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` is not defined. Something along the lines of (untested)

```
m4_ifndef([PKG_CHECK_MODULES], [dnl
m4_fatal([Could not find the PKG_CHECK_MODULES macro. Check that the pkg.m4 file is available and aclocal finds it (e.g. set ACLOCAL_PATH=/opt/local/share/aclocal).
])dnl
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([FOO], [foo])
```

Personally, I would go with `m4_pattern_forbid` and make sure OSX builds with homebrew work OOTB, and then document idiosyncrasies for building on rare and buggy systems like OSX with macports or SunOS without GNU tools in the INSTALL file.

Isn't it a bug in macports/OSX that `aclocal` there cannot find its `*.m4` files? Shouldn't there be a `dirlist` file pointing to `/opt/local/share/aclocal`? Or perhaps they macports users should have an `aclocal` in their `PATH` which actually finds the macports macro files?

In any case, I would not consider it my build systems's job to fix a buggy system. You need to draw the line somewhere.

Comment: Good idea about homebrew, I started a brew Formula...  Also, thanks for opening a PR to clean up the build system!

Comment: Writing a brew formula is not strictly necessary to make xnec2c build on a OSX/homebrew system, but it might help expose xnec2c build issues on OSX/homebrew.